# Some problems about channel in Fabric python SDK

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I try to follow the tutorial of the Hyperledger Fabric python SDK, but get a problem when creating channel. The error I got is shown in the following:

> Exception: [status: BAD_REQUEST
> info: "error applying config update to existing channel 'businesschannel': error authorizing update: error validating ReadSet: proposed update requires that key [Group]  /Channel/Application be at version 0, but it is currently at version 1"
> ]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you didn't remove your previous config before creating a new channel i.e `businesschannel`. See this line in your error `error applying config update to existing channel 'businesschannel`. If you are using docker then try below commands:-

1. `docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)`
2. `docker network prune -f`
3. `docker volume prune -f`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works! But when I just following the Jupyter notebook tutorial file, when I try to install the chaincode on the peer of org1. It got the error which is responses = loop.run_until_complete(cli.chaincode_install). The loop is not defined. But when I add loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() before. It shows This event loop is already running. Could u please tell me how to solve this problem? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not familiar with `python-sdk-go`. I answered the question based on the error that you have shared in the question. I'm sorry but I can help with this error.

Comment: If my answer helped you fix the error that you have asked in question then please accept it as an answer.